# Got this error on Python code "TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'" and unable to understand

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

`I am unable to resolve this error
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
**---> 13     score = FitnessFunction(population[i]**)

```
bestSolutions = []
    bestScores = []
    for iterationNumber in range(NO_OF_ITERATIONS):
      scores = []
      for i in range(len(population)):
        score = FitnessFunction(population[i])
        scores.append(score)
    
      newPopulation = PopulationUpdating(population, scores, iterationNumber)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-92b06f95aee0> in <module>
     12   scores = []
     13   for i in range(len(population)):
---> 14     score = FitnessFunction(population[i])
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

Comment: Make sure indentation of your code is correct, Python is sensitive at it.

Comment: Yes I checked this actually when I paste code here it shows like this

Comment: If this is the code you're running in your IDE, then it will never work, because indentation is messed up.

Comment: No, I run this code in googlecolab its not a indentation issue

Comment: argument using in fit method is actually callback**s**